# I want to sort pivot table multilevel

Tags: pandas, sorting, pivot-table

Created df:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
        'Name': ['ab', 'bc', 'Cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij'],
        'Ratings': [20, 21, 19, 18, 10, 5]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Type', 'Name', 'Ratings'], aggfunc='sum')
pivot.sort_values(['Type', 'Ratings'], ascending=False)

df3 = pivot.reset_index().sort_values(['Type', 'Ratings'], ascending=[True, False]).set_index(['Type', 'Name'])

print(df3)
```

Output :

```
Type Name       Ratings 
A    ab         20
     gh         10
B    bc         21
     ij          5
C    Cd         19
     ef         18
```

Required output:

```
Type Name       Ratings  
C    Cd         19
     ef         18
A    ab         20
     gh         10
B    bc         21
     ij          5
```

Output :

```
Ratings
Type Name       Ratings 
 A    ab         20
      gh         10
 B    bc         21
      ij          5
 C    Cd         19
      ef         18
```

Required output:

```
Type Name       Ratings  
C    Cd         19
     ef         18
A    ab         20
     gh         10
B    bc         21
     ij          5
```

Expected : As total ratings of c is 37,a : 30,B : 26`

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) to apply the custom order to level 0. Create the custom order with [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-sum) in descending order to place the highest sum `Type` first and the lowest sum `Type` last:

```
pivot = (
    df.pivot_table(index=['Type', 'Name'], aggfunc='sum')
        .sort_values('Ratings', ascending=False)
        .reindex(df.groupby('Type')['Ratings'].sum()
                 .sort_values(ascending=False).index,
                 axis=0, level=0)
)
```

`pivot`:

```
           Ratings
Type Name         
C    Cd         19
     ef         18
A    gh         20
     ab         10
B    bc         21
     ij          5
```

---

DataFrame used:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
    'Name': ['ab', 'bc', 'Cd', 'ef', 'gh', 'ij'],
    'Ratings': [10, 21, 19, 18, 20, 5]
})
```

```
  Type Name  Ratings
0    A   ab       10
1    B   bc       21
2    C   Cd       19
3    C   ef       18
4    A   gh       20
5    B   ij        5
```

Comment: I want to sort df in ascending/descending.I want to sort Type and Name with respect to measure'Ratings'This is just short df.I have 30 rows.

Comment: Okay. I misunderstood the first time. Try now.

Comment: Thank you.This solved my half problem.I want to sort both type and name column.for eg.       A    ab         10
                  gh         20                                                                                                           Here gh shloud be above ab

Comment: Okay. Sorted by both group total and Ratings now. See the edit.

Comment: Thank you.It works.just come in my mind what if  i added one more column(city).how to sort one more column.